# Throttling issues in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

We are seeing multiple requests from the front-end hitting the API at multiple times per second. This has been occurring since launch and while we have throttling in place as a band-aid to stop it killing the API, the source of the issue needs to be investigated and resolved.

Example output from the API logs when the throttling kicks in:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-06-19 00:14:43,464",
  "thread": "38",
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "[THROTTLE] request to /api/v1/profile from 203.97.65.100 blocked - quota 2/Second exceeded by 3",
  "data": {
    "IpAddress": "203.97.65.100"
  },
  "logger": "Services.Logging.Log4NetThrottleLogger"
},
{
  "timestamp": "2017-06-19 00:14:43,467",
  "thread": "43",
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "[THROTTLE] request to /api/v1/catalog from 203.97.65.100 blocked - quota 2/Second exceeded by 3",
  "data": {
    "IpAddress": "203.97.65.100"
  },
  "logger": "Services.Logging.Log4NetThrottleLogger"
},
{
  "timestamp": "2017-06-19 00:14:43,482",
  "thread": "28",
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "[THROTTLE] request to /api/v1/profile from 203.97.65.100 blocked - quota 2/Second exceeded by 4",
  "data": {
    "IpAddress": "203.97.65.100"
  },
  "logger": "Services.Logging.Log4NetThrottleLogger"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the problem code that is hitting the apis?

Comment: I just posted it above sir

Comment: Sorry, I meant the angular code that is making the request.

Comment: can you connect to me via message or skyp: priti.technophile please